# SSD not recognized in bios after Ubuntu crash

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I install zorin os on my hdd but due to some mistakes my hdd crashed along with zorin...when I bought a new SSD and replace it my ssd is not being detected..and my battery light keeps blinking...I tried many online fixes but my sata port shows empty...the SSD works fine when I use it with a sata-to-usb cable
I thought it is coz of driver issue but I didn't get a workaround
I really don't know what's wrong, Can anyone help plz

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, drivers are for OSes, nothing to do with BIOS/UEFI. If the drive isn't recognized then probably the SATA controller is faulty. Have you tried other ports?

Comment: @ChanganAuto no more sata Ports Its a laptop..thanks anyways